# Retrieving file content from Azure Blob

Tags: azure, email, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I want to send report by using sendgrid in Azure AA. Problem is, I'm forced to use apikey pass in plaintext in a script and I obviously want to avoid that at any cost. I figured I could save file with apikey in txt file somewhere hidden Azure Storage in  specific container. What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
(...)
$HTMLDetails = @{
Title = $Subject
Head = $CSS
}

$Username ="username"

$apikey = get-storageblobfilecontent -container x -blob y -file z | Out-String

$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $apikey -Force

$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Username, $Password

$Splat = @{
    To          =...
    Cc          =...
    Body       ="$(import-csv -delimiter ";" DiskReport.csv | ConvertTo-Html @HTMLDetails)"
    Subject     = $Subject
    smtpServer  ="smtp.sendgrid.net"
    From        ="AzureReporting@azure.com" 
    BodyAsHtml  = $True
    }

Send-MailMessage @Splat -Credential $Credential -Usessl -Port xxx
```

Is it actually possible to do? Retrieving file content from the VM is not an option, as Runbook scripts cannot reach VM's directly.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. If it's about hiding storage credentials, you can store creds within something like Azure KeyVault. Or take advantage of a SAS to offer temporary read-only access to a particular container or blob without ever worrying about passing the storage-account key anywhere.

Comment: Is this being run from an Azure Automation Account?

Comment: @tedsmitt yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in Get-AutomationPSCredential cmdlet inside of your runbook. At the Automation account level you can configure credentials that get stored securely, then bring them into your runbook (it is configured so that the output can never be written to host in plaintext).

Create a credential (for example 'MyApiKey') inside of the Credentials tab on the AA. Inside of your script use the following command `$apiKey = Get-AutomationPSCredential MyApiKey`

You can then pass that into the `$Credential` object.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/credentials#activities for more information on the utility.

Comment: that's even better! Thank you

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. If you are happy with the solution could you mark this is answered? Thanks :-)